# WakefulIntentService always getting killed in between execution

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, wakelock

I am listening to incoming sms by WakefulBroadcastReceiver, which spawns a WakefulIntentService to log in that sms to google spreadsheet.But the problem is that the Intent service gets killed in between of execution, hence the writing of the sms details to google spreadsheet does not complete.

Is it because of it being a time taking task(>10s)?
And if yes then how do I deal with it?

I am using wakefulIntentService because i want to handle the incoming sms event even while device sleeping. Initially I used an asynctask for the same, but that did not work while device was sleeping.

Comment: i'm using service to upload something in server. and usually take 3-5 minutes. i think your problem maybe in how you write the sms content in google spreadsheet

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Will share the code here soon

Comment: As i know . intent service will end after the last line code in your onHandleIntent execute. you can use logcat to check it be killed or it has done job.(I don't know english )